# What field should I search to solve delay like equations?

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations, recursion

I want to solve equations like:
$$
t f(t) + u(t-2) f(t-2) = \sin(t)
$$

It's like delay differential equations but without the derivative.

What field should I search in to solve this kind of equation?

Comment: Broadly speaking, I would call this a functional equation, but I'm not sure that's very helpful.

Comment: Looking at it I would want to do a laplace transform.

Comment: Nothing differential in the posted equation

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.*

You can solve the equation recursively:

1. If $t<2$, $u(t-2)=0$, so the equation becomes
   $$
   tf(t)=\sin(t) \implies f(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}{t}. \tag{1}
   $$
2. If $2<t<4$, $u(t-2)=1$ and the argument of $f(t-2)$ is less than $2$, so $f(t-2)=\frac{\sin(t-2)}{t-2}$ and
   $$
   f(t)=\frac{1}{t}\left(\sin(t)-\frac{\sin(t-2)}{t-2}\right). \tag{2}
   $$
3. If $4<t<6$, the argument of $f(t-2)$ is in the interval $(2,4)$, so it is given by $(2)$ with $t$ replaced with $t-2$, hence
   $$
   f(t)=\frac{1}{t}\left(\sin(t)-\frac{1}{t-2}\left(\sin(t-2)-\frac{\sin(t-4)}{t-4}\right)\right). \tag{3}
   $$

The pattern should be clear by now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there a general method to solve this kind of equations ?

Comment: I don't know if there is a general method to solve this kind of equation. As far as I know (which is very little), the method I used (called the method of steps) is  commonly used to solve [delay differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation#Solving_DDEs). There are other methods, though.